# Animate Toggle of Links for Stairstepped Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to use `.each()` and `.toggle()` or `.fadeToggle()` or an equivalent to create a 'stairstepped' animation using JS and jQuery on a website using Bootstrap 3.

I've a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JeffroDH/2xcv7cb1/

Essentially, when I click the 'Categories' link, I'd like the subcategories to unhide in rapid succession, but not all at the same time, so they appear to flow out, rather than just fading in as a block.  The animation could be a slide from the left, or simply a fadeToggle, but I can't seem to get `.each()`, .`delay()`, and `.fadeToggle()` to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't showing your CSS here, but I would accomplish this with a class. For example, in your category-dropin-item class, add:

```
max-height:0; 
transition: max-height .2s;
```

Then, in another class, maybe called show, add:

```
max-height:2em;
```

(you'll need to play with the value to get it to work right.) Then, in your JQuery, when a user clicks the Categories link, delay the addition of the show class. You should get a nice little falling transition.

Comment: All of the CSS here is within the Bootstrap framework.  I'll tinker with some stuff in the fiddle and see if I can update it.

Comment: While this doesn't use the technique i suggested, this pen may have some use for you: http://codepen.io/pedronauck/pen/fcaDw

Comment: I edited the fiddle to reflect the changes: The jQuery modifies the CSS property max-height directly when the categories link.  All the links' animations are still firing simultaneously.